# Showing resource folders in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I was trying to fix a problem where my logcat wasn't showing anything and during my attempts at fixing that, my resources folders that by default hang on the left side of eclipse disappeared. I've looked and can't find anywhere where to enable them again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this

**Window >> Open PErspective >> other >> select Resource**

or

**Window >> Show View >> Project Explorer** [image]

Comment: Thanks, to add to that though - It wasn't showing on the default menu, I had to go to Other..>>General>>Project Explorer

Comment: Yes there are more perspective and view next time look into it and rate and accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can start a new project. Or, if your informations are in there. you can check Start>>(Computer Users)>>workspace folder >>(Your project's name)>>Your project's includes.